# Ubuntu 12.04 cannot not shutdown and reboot automatically

Tags: 12.04, shutdown

I have 12.04 installed on my laptop, and recently I found that my laptop cannot shutdown, even if I press the shutdown button or:

```
sudo shutdown -h now
sudo shutdown -P now
sudo init 0
```

The system will close and screen becomes dark, but the system reboots automatically.

I'm not sure if I installed some software or updated some system software.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Some systems have a BIOS/UEFI setting which makes the system power on after power off. Can you check if you have that enabled?

Answer (score 0):

1. from the terminal `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="reboot=efi"`
3. save the file, close, and run in terminal `sudo update-grub`

Source: [Ubuntu 12.04 - Most Common Problems and Solutions](http://www.inforbiro.com/blog-eng/ubuntu-12-04-most-common-problems-and-solutions)

Comment: OP's problem is that the system can't power off, it always restarts, This solution is for when the system doesn't restart.